# Akka stream flows example

Tags: java, stream, akka

I am learning [Akka](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/), and I am having trouble to understand the ideas of [flows](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html). Precisely I would like to see how flows can be connected to each other.

Can you please provide me an example that perform the following tasks:

- Download a JSON array, zip file
- Unzip it
- Decode it to a stream of individual JSON objects
- Serialize the objects back to JSON
- Save the objects to a file

In the example, I am not interested in the actual implementation of JSON parsing or file downloading, I just want to see how such flow can be constructed using Akka.

My expectation is that everything will happen in a stream without impacting the memory, and by the time it will finish downloading the file(step 1) it will also finish saving it to a file(last step)

Comment: would you accept a Scala example?

Comment: @RoberMP, yeah sure